# Resultado: [object], [object] al importar un archivo JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Tengo un problema para obtener datos de un archivo JSON, cuándo intento obtener los datos de este archivo, obtengo como resultado: [object], [object]

```
{
  "categories": [
    {
      "categori_id": 1,
      "name": "drinks"
    },
    {
      "categori_id": 2,
      "name": "lunch"
    },
    {
      "categori_id": 3,
      "name": "food"
    },
    {
      "categori_id": 4,
      "name": "sea"
    }
  ],
  "products": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Lorem",
      "price": "60.000",
      "available": true,
      "best_seller": true,
      "categories": [
        1,
        4
      ],
      "img": "",
      "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas eu."
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "ipsum",
      "price": "20.000",
      "available": false,
      "best_seller": false,
      "categories": [
        4
      ],
      "img": "",
      "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas eu."
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "dolor",
      "price": "10.000",
      "available": true,
      "best_seller": true,
      "categories": [
        4
      ],
      "img": "",
      "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas eu."
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "name": "sit",
      "price": "35.000",
      "available": false,
      "best_seller": false,
      "categories": [
        1,
        2
      ],
      "img": "",
      "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas eu."
    },
    {
      "id": 5,
      "name": "amet",
      "price": "12.000",
      "available": true,
      "best_seller": true,
      "categories": [
        1,
        4
      ],
      "img": "http://lorempixel.com/200/100/food/",
      "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas eu."
    },
    {
      "id": 6,
      "name": "consectetur",
      "price": "120.000",
      "available": true,
      "best_seller": false,
      "categories": [
        1,
        4
      ],
      "img": "",
      "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas eu."
    },
    {
      "id": 7,
      "name": "adipiscing",
      "price": "50.000",
      "available": false,
      "best_seller": false,
      "categories": [
        1,
        3
      ],
      "img": "",
      "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas eu."
    },
    {
      "id": 8,
      "name": "elit",
      "price": "2000",
      "available": true,
      "best_seller": false,
      "categories": [
        1,
        3
      ],
      "img": "",
      "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas eu."
    },
    {
      "id": 9,
      "name": "Maecenas",
      "price": "150.000",
      "available": true,
      "best_seller": true,
      "categories": [
        2,
        4
      ],
      "img": "",
      "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas eu."
    },
    {
      "id": 10,
      "name": "eu",
      "price": "200.000",
      "available": false,
      "best_seller": true,
      "categories": [
        2,
        3
      ],
      "img": "",
      "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas eu."
    }
  ]
}
```

**Código JavaScript:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $.ajax({
    url: "category.json", // path to file
    dataType: 'json', // type of file (text, json, xml, etc)
     success: function(data) {
     /$.each(data, function(i, item) {
          console.log(item);

      });/

     jQuery.each( data, function( i, val ) {
  $( "body" ).append( document.createTextNode( " - " + val ) );
});
    },
    error: function() {
      alert("error");
    }
  });     

});
```

Por favor me gustaría saber que está pasando.

Comment: No entiendo tu error, cual es el resultado esperado? Categoria -> Array productos?

Answer (score 1):

Buenas, deberías "entrar" en el JSON. Es decir, en vez de `console.log(item)` pon `console.log(item.categories);`

Para seguir recorriendo el array, deberías hacer un for, siendo i=0 y hasta item.categories.length.

`console.log(item.categories[i]);`

Answer (score 1):

Si mal no veo el codigo creo que deberias volver a recorrer lo que te viene dentro del primer for each.

```
$.ajax({
   url: "category.json", // path to file
   dataType: 'json', // type of file (text, json, xml, etc)
    success: function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(i, item) {
         console.log(item);

        jQuery.each( item, function( i, val ) {
             $( "body" ).append( document.createTextNode( " - " + val ) );
        }); 

     });


   },
   error: function() {
     alert("error");
   }
 });     

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Para imprimir un atributo en especifico, debes declarar cuál es ese atributo en la función each() ya que se tratan de arreglos y luego recorrer ese arreglo dentro de otro each() de la siguiente forma:

```
$.each(data.products, function() {
   $.each(this, function(key, value) {
      console.log(key + " - " + value)
   })
})
```

Espero que te sirva!

Answer (score 0):

Comprueba que tu servidor está enviando los datos en formato `application/json` en vez de `text/plain`. Tu función de `jquery` está esperando los datos en formato json al poner:

dataType: 'json'

Por otro lado, lo de `[object][object]` es la forma en que se serializan los datos que estás recibiendo. Si quieres verlos en forma de árbol, mándalos a la consola del navegador con  `console.log(datos)`.

Answer (score 0):

No entiendo muy bien lo que necesita, pero tiene que tener en claro que su JSON se compone de 2 arreglos, por lo tanto 1 each no es suficiente para obtener todos los datos que usted quiere.

```
$.each(data.categories, function(index,value){
    console.log(value.categori_id + " " + value.name);
});
$.each(data.products, function(index,value){
    console.log(value.id + " " + value.name + " " + value.price);
});
```